# Exhaust fan/light wiring for 50 yr old house

Tags: wiring, exhaust-fan

[image]I'm replacing a bathroom exhaust fan/ light. Bathroom has a switch to control each separately. Cable from ceiling has a black wire, a white wire, and a bare aluminum wire. New fan has two white wires, one black, and one blue.

What do I hook the blue wire to? And the bare aluminum goes to the green ground, correct?

Comment: Pictures of wiring? Also please clarify: Does the old setup have one switch or two? Were the old fan and light "together" or two separate devices in different locations?

Comment: Two switches. Old fan was one unit and had a switch for the fan, and a separate switch for the light. Trying to figure out how to post a pic....

Comment: Did the pic pop up?

Comment: Picture is helpful. 1 - That ground really *does* look more like aluminum then copper. Are the other wires aluminum and copper? 2 - What is the bit of red in the end of the cable?

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring at the switch box please? I suspect there's more than one thing wrong in this picture...

Comment: That looks like a /3 cable where the red wire controlled the light and the black controlled the fan (or vice-versa) and someone's cut off the red wire. Were there originally 4 wires there (including the bare ground)? Pics (without disconnecting _anything_!) of the wiring at the fan/light switches would be very helpful. Also, if this really is aluminum wiring, make sure your connectors are rated for Al. You'll get lots of info about that in answers as they appear.

Comment: My guess is that that's a /3 with no ground and the "bare" wire is a red that's been stripped way back to the cable jacket.